# How can I predict new data in R after regress model?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, predict

I want to plot and generate new data based on my Regression Model which I created:

```
Trend <- seq(1:length(Daten$TSLAC))

TISPYNVDA_TSLA <- lm(TSLAC ~ Trend + SPYC * NVDAC, data = Daten)

summary(TISPYNVDA_TSLA)

plot(predict(TISPYNVDA_TSLA), type = "l", 
     xlab="geschätzte Werte der abh. Variablen", 
     ylab="geschätzte Residuen", main="Residuenplot", pch=20)

lines(Daten$TSLAC, col="red")
```

As seen above, I created a trend sequence for the creation of future data with:

```
newline <- data.frame(wt=predict(TISPYNVDA_TSLA))
```

The function:

```
TISPYNVDA_TSLA <- lm(TSLAC ~ Trend + SPYC * NVDAC, data = Daten)
```

creates the regression. After that, I plot the regression together with the real data on TSLAC (Tesla Close Price).

Then I want to predict further afterwards as a "future prediction".

How can I do that?

I tried the predict() function, but it's not working:

```
lines(252:350,predict(newline,newdata=newline))
```

252 because the data is going to 251, then it should predict in the future.

Comment: Could you post your output?

Comment: In `predict(newline, newdata=newline)`, I think you want `predict(TISPYNVDA_TSLA, newdata=newline)` instead.

Comment: @smanski thanks for the quick answer. However, if I change it to your idea my output says: "Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'SPYC' not found" Is there any other way to generate a new predictive plot or did i made a mistake?

Comment: @GonzaloDonoso Thanks for the quick answer, my output is: "Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "data.frame"" Maybe the way i generate is a little bit wrong?

Comment: @Aron1894 `newdata` in `predict` needs to be a dataframe with columns for all variables used in your linear model.  When you say "future predictions", you need to specify what these future X values are.

Comment: @smanski thank you for the info! Could you maybe provide me with some hints on how to get there. Like should include in my predict function what steps the data should be predicted on the X value?